# Use Applications on post-boot mounted SD card?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, mount

In order to increase free space on /data , I moved some 15Mb of application files to an ext2 partition on external SD card  that is mounted on /data/HWUserData/mnt

Specifically, I moved

> /data/data/com.opera.browser/lib/*

to

> /data/HWUserData/mnt/lib

and symlinked.

This worked fine until reboot, as the SD Card partition is not mounted at boot time - The Phone now says that Opera is not installed.

Is there some way I can tell android to rescan, or redo what ever it needs to do to detect that opera is installed and integral once again after mounting the sd-card? Does it have to do with the dalvik cache?

Another issue/solution is getting the sd-card mounted at boot-time, I know, but that is not this question.

Comment: Reading this discussion may help: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36779/how-can-i-symlink-the-cache-folder-on-boot

Answer (score 1):

From [this XDA discussion](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1229654):

> Create a script in /etc/init.d to do it. You'll need to remount / to
>   read+write first though.

And solution:

> Thanks for your help! I'm quite firm in shell-operations, I just
>   didn't think I could just put a script to /etc/init.d! :)
>
> I'v created a shell-script named 07sdcard and with the content: Code:
>
> `#!/system/bin/sh rootrw ln -s /mnt/external1 /sdcard-ext rootro`
>
> Works geat! :)

Comment: As far as I understand, (and this has been my experience), any changes to / will be reset on reboot as the root image is unpacked.

Comment: /etc is actually simlinked to /system/etc which will remain unaffected by a reboot, although, reinstalling/upgrading the ROM will most likely wipe out any customizations.

Comment: Also, to add to the instructions. Once the sdcard is auto-mounted on boot, you can use other apps to help you clear up space. S2E is a great one, although, it is only officially supported on CM. Link2SD is a bit more to set up, but I think it supports many different ROMs.

Comment: on the Huawei U8350 (Android 2.2.2) there is no /etc/init.d and no init scripts in /etc - the init scripts are in the root.